How to use Date() within the "vscode.commands.registerCommand" lambda body
I would like to provide a command to VS Code, so I follow the tutorial Your First Extention through to the end. For extra credit I am asked to "Contribute another command that displays current time in an information message." My attempt fails. When I attempt to use the Date() function within the lambda body of my "helloworld.helloTime" command. When I run the command my Information message contains:
Hello, the current time is function getHours() { [native code] }:function getMinutes() { [native code] }

I am hardly a Javascript programmer, much less Typescript. I have spent several hours trying to figure this out, have read much about passing functions to functions and the this context and am now hopelessly lost. Why can I not use Date() in this context?
import * as vscode from 'vscode';

export function activate(context: vscode.ExtensionContext) {
    
    console.log('Congratulations, your extension "helloworld" is now active!');

    const disposable = vscode.commands.registerCommand('helloworld.helloWorld', () => {
        vscode.window.showInformationMessage('Hello VS Code!');
    });

    const disposable1 = vscode.commands.registerCommand('helloworld.helloTime', () => {
        const d = new Date();
        vscode.window.showInformationMessage('Hello, the current time is ' + d.getHours + ':' + d.getMinutes);
    });

    context.subscriptions.push(disposable);
    context.subscriptions.push(disposable1);
}

export function deactivate() {}


Those are function calls to the methods of Date, so use
d.getHours()
d.getMinutes()

See, e.g., MDN documentation Date.getHours()

Please see the question : d.getHours() + ':' + d.getMinutes fails in this context.

Oops, didn't notice the parentheneses.

So it works now?

Yes, thank you. Sorry for the snarky comment. A quick read didn''t see the parentheses. From the output to the message window I would never have guesses that I was missing braces.
